# how to get tkinter input outside of function within class

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I get access to variables (ifrequency and iperiod) outside of the class?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

class Parameters:

    def __init__(self,master):

        tk.Label(master,text='frequency').grid(row=0)
        tk.Label(master,text='period').grid(row=1)
        
        self.options1 = ['D1', 'D2']
        self.options2 = ['daily', 'monthly']
        
        self.mycombo1 = ttk.Combobox(master, value=self.options1)
        self.mycombo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
        self.mycombo1.grid(row=0, column=1)      
        
        self.mycombo2 = ttk.Combobox(master, value=self.options2)
        self.mycombo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
        self.mycombo2.grid(row=1, column=1)        

        self.myButton = tk.Button(master, text="Go", command=self.clicker).grid(row=3,column=1)              
      
    def clicker(self):
        ifrequency = self.mycombo1.get()
        iperiod = self.mycombo2.get()
        return ifrequency, iperiod
    
p = Parameters(root)
   
root.mainloop()

print(p.ifrequency)
```

The code gives the error:
"AttributeError: 'Parameters' object has no attribute 'ifrequency'" when running the final line.

For a bit of context, I have built some code to get output from an API. I want the user to be able to pick the inputs (e.g. frequency, period) using a form and then have the main program call the API and using these inputs. My API code works but I need to get the user inputs assigned to a variable. I can do it but that variable is stuck in the function/class and I can't figure out the correct way to get it out.

This is my first question here (usually someone else has asked before me) so apologies if I have made any mistakes. Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Inside the clicker method, make sure the variables that you're assigning are attributes of the class. Instead of ifrequency, it should be self.ifrequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifrequency` and `iperiod` are not assigned to `self` and are just in the function's local scope so they disappear after `clicker` returns, and since it is called by the tkinter button, it's return value dosn't do anything. so try changing `clicker` so it assigns them to `self`

```py
    def clicker(self):
        self.ifrequency = self.mycombo1.get()
        self.iperiod = self.mycombo2.get()
```